# Cannot click using selenium with Python 2.7

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, click, web-crawler

I'm new to web crawling and would really appreciate your help. I'm trying to select the range of data to download from a government database. The URL is shown in the code block. Ideally I want to click "Select all" for Period, "GDP (Million N.T.$,at Current Prices)" for Indicators, and "Data" for Type.

**Problem: I can only click "Select all".**

Question 1: What's wrong with codes?

Question 2: I also tried with **xpath** but it didn't work. Here there exists multiple //option[@value='1' in a webpage. I don't know if that's the reason. If yes, then how should I write the xpath?

Question 3: If I want to click "Select all" for all 3 variables. How could I do it?

Thank you for your patience!

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class gdp_spider2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gdp_spider2'
    allowed_domains = ['statdb.dgbas.gov.tw/']
    start_urls = ['http://statdb.dgbas.gov.tw/pxweb/Dialog/varval.asp?ma=NA8101A1Q&ti=Principal%20Figures%282008SNA%29-Quarterly&path=../PXfileE/NationalIncome/&lang=1&strList=L']

    def __init__(self):

    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(response.url)
        driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Select all').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('GDP (Million N.T.$,at Current Prices)').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Data').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='SUBMIT']").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Select all').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('select[name="values2"]>option[value="4"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('select[name="values3"]>option[value="1"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="SUBMIT"]').click()
```

or using `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Select all').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//option[contains(text(),"GDP (Million N.T.$,at Current Prices)")]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//option[contains(text(),"Data")]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="SUBMIT"]').click()
```